# What am I missing in my function (return an array of element that is greater than the element to its right)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a function that finds all elements in the given array, such that each element is greater than all elements to the right of it.

Examples

```
leader([2, 3, 20, 15, 8, 3]) ➞ [20, 15, 8, 3]

leader([2, 3, 20, 15, 8, 25, 3]) ➞ [25, 3]
```

Here is my function :

```js
function leader( array ) {
  return array.slice(array.indexOf(Math.max(...array)))
  }
console.log(leader([8, 7, 1, 2, 10, 3, 5]))
```

The test that makes me fail is when this array is called:

```
leader([8, 7, 1, 2, 10, 3, 5]) // "Expected : [10,5], Received : [10,3,5]"
```

Comment: Maybe a reduce but I have trouble with adding initial value to the reduce function, even if i call array.reduce(function, []) it will return me index[0] as initial value.. someone know why ?

Comment: Read the description again. The result is not "everything to the right of the biggest element". You also need to make sure there are no elements [..., a, b, ...] where b is smaller than or equal to a.

Comment: I know I just was locked cause I couldn't find out how to filter the result

Comment: Then look at the new problem you need to solve: ignore everything you already wrote, because it doesn't matter. Just focus on "if you have an array of elements, how do you remove elements that aren't smaller than the previous element", and by rephrasing it that way, it almost writes itself: you compare an element to the previous element, and then either throw it away, or you keep it.

Comment: Thank you it is helping me a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just finding the index of the max element isn't enough, because the elements that come after the max element may not be in decreasing order. Use `.filter` instead.

```js
function leader( array ) {
  return array.filter(
    (num, i) => array.slice(i + 1).every(
      otherNum => num > otherNum
    )
  );
}
console.log(leader([8, 7, 1, 2, 10, 3, 5]))
```

Comment: that arrow function definitely needs some argument or statement parentheses, so it's not as confusing at first glace, with `(otherNum) => (num > otherNum)` for maximum legibility =)

Comment: I don't understand how it filters the array.. it start with the second value and render only values that are greater than the previous one ? If you could explain thank you

Comment: @YoëlZerbib The `array.slice(i + 1)` constructs a subarray containing all elements on the right of the element being considered. Then the `.every` checks that every element in that subarray is less than the element being considered

Comment: And there is no need to add condition if index is the last element ? Because when it checks 5 it slice with index+1 ? thank you for your time again

Comment: @YoëlZerbib For the last element, the `.slice` array will be empty: `[]` and `.every` called on an empty array gives `true`, so no additional code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce from the right side.

This approach takes a single loop only.

```js
function leader( array ) {
    return array.reduceRight((r, v) => {
        if (!r.length || v > r[0]) r.unshift(v);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

console.log(leader([8, 7, 1, 2, 10, 3, 5]))
```